# Cloudera Kafka can not run

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I installed Zookeeper and tried to install Kafka0.8.0 on Cloudera5.4.4. It successfully deployed, but when I ran it, it failed. The error log as following:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/kafka/server.log'
```

I really have no any idea.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this problem before, the default maximum memory of brokers were set to 0MB by Cloudera(it seems a bug of Cloudeara), it caused Kafka could not get run, and the parameter fetch.message.max.bytes also was set to low by default. Check the stderr installation log, search keyword ERROR, otherwise the log too messy to check. You would find the root error message. The message above `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/kafka/server.log'` is not the root exception.